# GMSMapView didTapMarker delegate method centers the tapped marker if returned false

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

What I want is that when I tap on a marker in mapView then, it should display the infoWindow for that marker as well as it should do one more thing.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
   selectMarker(selectMarker: marker)
   markerTappedHandler?(marker)
   return false
}
```

So, I am returning false from the above method.
The problem is that it is centering the marker in the mapView. I don't want that.

Anybody knows the solution?

Comment: You should return the true in your method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `selectedMarker` in `didTap` delegate method and `return true`, i.e.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
{
    self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    markerTappedHandler?(marker)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you set snippet property of marker? marker.snippet = "Your info window data"

Comment: Actually, I missed the line 

self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker 

in the above code.
This is working, Thanks :)

Comment: Sure..Happy coding..:)